# Purpose of magento\generated\metadata\global.php file and is it safe to delete this file?

Tags: magento2, module

I encountered the following issue when I have moved Magento 2 module into production with the command `setup:di: compile`

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setActive() on boolean in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:27\nStack trace:
> /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu('...')

I found a solution to delete `magento\generated\metadata\global.php` file which worked.

Does anyone know the purpose of `global.php` file and is it safe to delete it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look for any errors that occur while Magento is in developer mode, without running `di:compile`. You'll want to find a root cause of your issue, rather than trying to delete core Magento files.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/code-generation.html) says

> "The code compiler creates generated/metadata/global.php, which is a
>   PHP serialized map of all constructor definitions mixed with object
>   linking configuration defined in di.xml. di.xml is the dependency
>   injection configuration. There is a global app/etc/di.xml and there
>   can one defined for every module ."

Answer (score 0):

Well looking into M2 core if the global.php is missing it runs the environment in developer mode rather than compiled mode (check `vendor/magento/framework/App/EnvironmentFactory.php` getMode method). I have no idea what that means in terms of performance and why running in compiled mode causes the error you mentioned since none of this is documented...

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend to delete the file, as Magento is running in Developer mode without it, as `ConfigLoader\Compiled::getFilePath(Area::AREA_GLOBAL)` resolves to /generated/metadata/global.php:

```
 private function getMode()
{
    if (file_exists(ConfigLoader\Compiled::getFilePath(Area::AREA_GLOBAL))) {
        return Compiled::MODE;
    }

    return Developer::MODE;
}
```